# nextJS upload image to external cloud

Tags: javascript, next.js, formidable

```
import { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import formidable from "formidable"
var fs = require('fs');
var FormData = require('form-data');

export const config = {
api: {
  bodyParser: false, // Defaults to true. Setting this to false disables body parsing and allows you to consume the request body as stream or raw-body.
},
};

const readFile = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) => {
const options = {
  uploadDir: `./public/upload`,
  keepExtensions: true,
}
const form = formidable(options)
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
        if(err) reject(err)
        resolve({fields, files})
        var bodyData = new FormData();
        bodyData.append('files', fs.createReadStream("./public/upload/"+files.file.newFilename));
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        const result = await fetch('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: bodyData,
        })
        const data = await result.json()
        if(data){
            res.send(data)
        }
        res.send(bodyData)
    })
})
```

}

```
const handler: NextApiHandler = async (req, res) => {
await readFile(req, res)
}

export default handler
```

Here this is my code, and when i call this, return me Failed to Fetch

I try lot of things lot really working, the variable files returns me well the file who i send in my body.

Comment: Please provide code as code, not images

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence